# Sending String from Java to C (Socket)

Tags: java, c, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send some string from A Java client to a C server using C.
First I send the length of the String. Then, I allocate the memory manually in C
and finally I send the String character by character.

The problem that sometimes I get the right String and some times I get the whole String + Extra other unknown Character (like I am allocating more than I get).

Here is the Java Code:

```
protected void send(String data){
    short dataLength=(short)data.length();
    try {
        out.write(dataLength);
    for (int i=0; i<data.getBytes().length ;i++)
    {
        out.write(data.getBytes()[i]);
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

And here is the C code :

```
void read4(int sock, int *data)
{

    char dataRecv;
    char* memoireAllouee=NULL;
    int stringLength;
    int i=0;
    recv(sock, (char*)&dataRecv, sizeof(dataRecv), 0) ;
    *data = dataRecv;
    stringLength=dataRecv;
    memoireAllouee=malloc(sizeof(char)*stringLength);
    if (memoireAllouee==NULL)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    for (i=0;i<stringLength;i++)
    {
        recv(sock, (char*)&dataRecv, sizeof(dataRecv), 0) ;
        *data = dataRecv;
        memoireAllouee[i]=dataRecv;
    }
    printf("\n\n%d\n\n\n",stringLength);
    printf("\n%s\n",memoireAllouee);
}
```

If you think also that this method is not optimal can you help me with a faster one?

Comment: @trutheality: If you copy-and-paste the involved line on each routine into an answer, that would make a pretty excellent answer.

Comment: @sarnold I took a look in the docs and it looks like `out` is probably a [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html), and if so, the matching method is `write( int )` which writes the bottom 8 bits of the `int` to the stream. That explains why the length is being transmitted correctly (or close to it, it would have been much worse if it were really sending the `short`). It also means that the conversion to `short` is either completely unnecessary, or an attempt to save 16 bits of space in the temporary variable storing the length.

Comment: @truthreality: Your answer is the wright one !.. I was very stupid, I didn't pay attention for the char in the C side.
So this what happens : When I send a String <127 char Every thing is OK and when I send a String >127 char many random cases happens... (writing the String and other strange charachter, not writing the string at all,...)

Thank you Again.

Ah just another thing, For information (for others). I have converted the short to an array of 2 bytes an just send it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your second question:

```
for (int i=0; i<data.getBytes().length ;i++)
{
    out.write(data.getBytes()[i]);
}
```

should be just:

```
out.write(data.getBytes());
```

and

```
for (i=0;i<stringLength;i++)
{
    recv(sock, (char*)&dataRecv, sizeof(dataRecv), 0) ;
    *data = dataRecv;
    memoireAllouee[i]=dataRecv;
}
```

should be:

```
int offset= 0;
while (offset < stringLength)
{
    int count = recv(sock, &memoireAllouee[offset], stringLength-offset 0) ;
    if (count == 0)
        // premature EOS .. do something
        break;
    if (count == -1)
        // Error ... do something
        break;
    offset += count;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
protected void send(String data){
    short dataLength=(short)data.length();
    try {
        out.write(dataLength);
    for (int i=0; i<data.getBytes().length ;i++)
    {
        out.write(data.getBytes()[i]);
    }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

For starters, you're recomputing the entire `getBytes()` array *twice* for *every character*.  Save the `byte[]` to a variable `byteArray` and use that -- you're making this take quadratic time, completely unnecessarily.  Additionally, why not just call `out.write(byteArray)` directly, instead of doing the `for` loop?

Secondly, `data.length()` isn't always equal to `data.getBytes().length()`.  Make sure you're writing `byteArray.length` instead of just `data.length()`.

Finally, make sure you're using a consistent charset on both ends.  The string-to-byte-array mapping is heavily dependent on the `Charset`, so be sure it's the same `Charset` on both sides so you don't run into encoding issues.